# Is std::vector<T>::resize( n, val ) sufficient for initialisation?

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, initialization

This is a C++11-specific question.
Assume I have a vector `std::vector<T> v` already used, and that I want to resize it to `n` elements initialised with an existing value `T val`. (Typical usecase: vector is the member of an instance being recycled).

What are the pros/cons of the following ways, and which is most efficient?

1) Is `std::vector<T>::resize( n, val )` sufficient for initialisation?

```
v.clear();
v.resize( n, val );
```

2) If not, then I assume the following is correct?

```
v.clear();
v.resize(n);
std::fill( v.begin(), v.end(), val );
```

3) How about swapping?

```
v.swap( std::vector<T>( n, val ) );
```

Comment: If this is a duplicate, please link to the solution, I'll vote for closing it.

Comment: Why do you want to resize it? To free the memory?

Comment: @black Typical case: this is a class-member and I'm recycling the instance.

Comment: [`v.assign(n, val);`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/assign) is probably the shortest method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(4)

```
std::fill(v.begin(), std::min(v.begin() + n, v.end()), val);
v.resize(n, val);
```

If T has suitable assignment behavior which is at least cheaper than constructing a new one, then use (4). This is the case for T = int (assign and construct are the same) and T = std::string (assigning can be faster than constructing, as it may be able to use existing buffer).

If T has the same cost of assignment and construction (eg T = int), then (1) could also be used for clarity without loss of performance.

If T cannot be assigned or, for some reason, assigning is more costly than constructing (rare) then use (1)

(1) could be simplified by using `v.assign(n, val);` (kudos to @Casey)

I don't know if (4) would be the same performance-wise using `assign`. I don't know if assign will (ironic, given the name) assign the new elements to existing ones, or construct them anew.

Edit: A possible improvement to (4), which I haven't tested. It can avoid the overhead of copying/moving during a change in vector capacity.

```
if (n <= v.capacity())
{
    std::fill(v.begin(), std::min(v.begin() + n, v.end()), val);
    v.resize(n, val);
}
else
{
    v.assign(n, val);
}
```

Comment: I guess 4 is only advantageous if n is greater than current size too?

Comment: Can `fill` write beyond `v.end()` if n > old size??

Comment: I don't think this is faster than `assign`: you first fill the existing buffer with the new value. Then `resize` copies the buffer to a new buffer, doing a new `val` construction on all new buffer entries. Consider: (4) is like (1), just that you replaced that `clear` call, which does nothing but call destructors that have to be called anyway.

Comment: @FelixDombek It may be faster in the case of strings. Fill calls assignment operator which can be faster than copy constructor. Resize can use move operator. assign I suspect uses only copy constructor.

Comment: Yeah I was considering adding this option 4. The problem here is that if n > the original size, you'll have to move all the values from beginning to end. Unlike the other options, the move operation (which could very well be a copy for non-movable types) can be expensive.

Comment: @IdeaHat You could possibly optimize further by checking if the new size exceeds the capacity or not.

Answer (score 8):

Why not use the interface that's designed for exactly this job?

```
v.assign(n, val);
```

[Documentation Here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/assign)

Comment: Do you know if this function is guaranteed to use the assignment operator on any elements that already exist in the vector?

Comment: The implementation is up to the library implementer. The standard does not specify how it must work. I would expect it to use assignment on existing items, in-place copy construction on new ones and if the vector shrinks as a result, inplace-destruction.

Comment: If it's not guaranteed then it might not be the most performant way.

Comment: I can surely guarantee that it will absolutely be the most performant way. The library maintainers are free to include compile-time optimisations based on the type traits of T and the before-and-after sizes of v. Note that there is a performance guarantee in the standard.

Comment: :) I'm torn, I think your and Neil's answer are equally informative and relevant.

Comment: If a type has faster assignment operator behaviour than copy constructor behaviour and a compiler can use only the latter if it wishes, how can you so surely guarantee it? Linear guarantee can be misleading. Two things can both be linear and do the same job, but one takes 1000 times longer than the other.

Comment: Since assignment is most correctly implemented in terms of construction (at least for a type exhibiting any form of exception guarantee), I think we can consider the "assignment is faster" case as an unusual corner case. i.e. not worth worrying about until performance measuring proves it to be an impediment to the user experience.

Comment: It's not uncommon for types to make use of existing allocated resources if possible when performing assignment. This happens with vectors and strings. If v contains a huge amount of vectors or strings, the performance difference can be noticeable.

Comment: In order for this to be true one would have to forego exception safety, or mandate that assignment is `noexcept`. `std::vector::assign` (at least in libc++) os coded to cover this case.

Comment: I don't understand your point. Vector assignment operator is not noexcept and it is exception safe.

Comment: SFNAE allows assignment of elements of vectors to be very efficient if the elements themselves have noexcept copy operators, since the vector code can then take a shortcut.

Answer (score 3):

(1) is enough. (3) also works. The difference is that (1) doesn't free the memory if new size is less than current. (3) always allocates new chunk of memory and deletes the old one.

(2) is slower than (1) in general, because it first default-constructs the elements, then assigns them. It may even not compile if `T` is not default-constructible.

Comment: Good :) I guess practice and _ad hoc_ testing will determine between (1) and (3) depending on the cases.

Answer (score 3):

Lets break it down to show the differences between each of these. I'll use n as the new size, m as the old size.

1.

```
v.clear();//keeps the same buffer, but calls the destructor on all the values
v.resize(n, val);//only makes a new buffer if the value is bigger, does no moves.
```

2.

```
v.clear();//keeps the same buffer, but calls the destructor on all the values
v.resize(n);//initializes all the values to default
std::fill( v.begin(), v.end(), val );//initializes all the values again to the new value
```

3.

```
v.swap( std::vector<T>( n, val ) );//calls destructor on all values in v, cannot reuse the buffer, initializes all the values to the new value
```

The differences are subtle but real. 1 *can* (but is not guarenteed to) reuse the buffer, which can save on memory overhead. 2 is the same as 1 but does a double reinitialize. 3 is the same as 1 but it cannot reuse the buffer.

Personally I think that the differences between the three is too subtle to matter in most cases, and 1 is the most readable.

Comment: Very good, and thank you for the personal opinion on 1 vs 3 :)

Comment: 1 IS guaranteed to reuse the buffer.

Comment: @NeilKirk iff n <= m, which is not specified in the code. If that is the case, then he shouldn't do the resize, as assignment can be faster than destruction and reinitialization.